# How to get the file size given a path?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have a path to file contained in an NSString.  Is there a method to get its file size?

Answer (score 137):

This one liner can help people:

```
unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:someFilePath error:nil] fileSize];
```

This returns the file size in Bytes.

Comment: I like this one.  But what measurement is this in?  bytes, Kb, etc?  Thanks too.

Comment: bytes - the measurement is bytes

Comment: What happens if your file is larger than `INT_MAX` bytes in size? You might want to cast the result to `size_t` or `unsigned long long int`, which allows accurate reporting of the size of large files (> 2 GB).

Comment: The actual return value of the method is `unsigned long long`, so `int` isn't fit to be here.

Answer (score 73):

Bear in mind that fileAttributesAtPath:traverseLink: is deprecated as of Mac OS X v10.5. Use `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` instead, described at the [same URL](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:) thesamet mentions.

With the caveat that I'm an Objective-C newbie, and I'm ignoring errors that might occur in calling `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`, you can do the following:

```
NSString *yourPath = @"Whatever.txt";
NSFileManager *man = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary *attrs = [man attributesOfItemAtPath: yourPath error: NULL];
UInt32 result = [attrs fileSize];
```

Comment: This code leaks the alloced FileManager. I recommend you simply use the NSFileManager.defaultManager Singleton to avoid this.

Answer (score 16):

In case some one needs a Swift version:

```
let attr: NSDictionary = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(path)
print(attr.fileSize())
```

Answer (score 12):

[CPU raises with attributesOfItemAtPath:error:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580422/cpu-raises-with-attributesofitematpatherror) 
You should use [stat](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html).

```
#import <sys/stat.h>

struct stat stat1;
if( stat([inFilePath fileSystemRepresentation], &stat1) ) {
      // something is wrong
}
long long size = stat1.st_size;
printf("Size: %lld\n", stat1.st_size);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using fileSystemRepresentation rather than UTF8String here?

Comment: You are right. HFS+ defines a standard Unicode decomposition ("canonical decomposition") for filenames. -UTF8String is not guaranteed to return the proper composition; -fileSystemRepresentation is.[1](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/StringWithCString)

Comment: @ParagBafna I know this is an old thread but do you know how I could use the `stat` structure in swift?

Answer (score 8):

If you want only file size with bytes just use,

```
unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:yourAssetPath error:nil] fileSize];
```

**[NSByteCountFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbytecountformatter)** string conversion of filesize (from Bytes) with precise KB, MB, GB ... Its returns like `120 MB` or `120 KB`

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *attrs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:yourAssetPath error:&error];
if (attrs) {
    NSString *string = [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:fileSize countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleBinary];
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Following the answer from Oded Ben Dov, I would rather use an object here:

```
NSNumber * mySize = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:someFilePath error:nil] fileSize]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2:

```
do {
    let attr: NSDictionary = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(path)
    print(attr.fileSize())
} catch {
        print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will give File size in Byte...

```
uint64_t fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:_filePath error:nil] fileSize];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3.x and above you can use:

```
do {
    //return [FileAttributeKey : Any]
    let attr = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)
    fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64

    //or you can convert to NSDictionary, then get file size old way as well.
    let attrDict: NSDictionary = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath) as NSDictionary
    fileSize = dict.fileSize()
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your code.  You define attrDict, but you call dict.fileSize.

Answer (score 0):

Swift4:

```
        let attributes = try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: path)
        let fileSize = attributes[.size] as! NSNumber
```