# How to find size of a MP3 file in iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the file size given a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815471/how-to-get-the-file-size-given-a-path)

I am trying to find the size of a MP3 file on iPhone programmatically. (THIS FILE IS LOADED FROM ITUNES TO IPHONE AND THIS FILE IS NOT WITHIN APP DIRECTORY)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to successfully to do that.

What classes or APIs should I use, please let me know.

Comment: you can export the file to local temp directory, get its size and then delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is not within directory, app directory, yo do not have access to file, therefore are unable to perform any operation to calculate the size. This is due to iOS sandbox behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it is an mp3 file does not matter. You just treat it as a normal file.
Look at the method `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` of `NSFileManager`, and at the method `fileSize` of NSDictionary, it should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry, I will edit my question. Mp3 in question is loaded from itunes to iphone and is not within application directory.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:YourFilePath error:nil] fileSize];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry, I will edit my question. Mp3 in question is loaded from itunes to iphone and is not within application directory.