# Delete files from directory inside Document directory?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

I have created a Temp directory to store some files:

```
//MARK: -create save delete from directory
func createTempDirectoryToStoreFile(){
    var error: NSError?
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
    tempPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Temp")

    if (!NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(tempPath!)) {

        NSFileManager.defaultManager() .createDirectoryAtPath(tempPath!, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil, error: &error)
   }
}
```

It's fine, now I want to delete all the files that are inside the directory... I tried as below:

```
func clearAllFilesFromTempDirectory(){

    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    var tempDirPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Temp")
    var directoryContents: NSArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(tempDirPath, error: error)!

    if error == nil {
        for path in directoryContents {
            let fullPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path as! String)
            let removeSuccess = fileManager.removeItemAtPath(fullPath, error: nil)
        }
    }else{

        println("seomthing went worng \(error)")
    }
}
```

I notice that files are still there... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should update your Xcode.

Comment: Otherwise you will be left behind. You should always be at least using the apple store version

Comment: i dont get you???is this really due to xcode version

Comment: That's because your code wont compile in most people's machines

Comment: oh thanks...will update tonight

Comment: If you need ti delete all files and subfolder files you need to use enumeratorAtURL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32814710/2303865

Comment: no but i need to delete all the files from document directory except a directory..is that possible?

Comment: `dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Temp")` not working in swift 3

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Two things, use the `temp` directory and second pass an error to the `fileManager.removeItemAtPath` and place it in a if to see what failed. Also you should not be checking if the error is set but rather whether a methods has return data.

```
func clearAllFilesFromTempDirectory(){

    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    var tempDirPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Temp")
    var directoryContents: NSArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(tempDirPath, error: error)?

    if directoryContents != nil {
        for path in directoryContents {
            let fullPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path as! String)
            if fileManager.removeItemAtPath(fullPath, error: error) == false {
                println("Could not delete file: \(error)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        println("Could not retrieve directory: \(error)")
    }
}
```

To get the correct temporary directory use `NSTemporaryDirectory()`

Comment: thanks i get this error as Could not delete file: 0x0000000000000000

Comment: Hmm that is a null pointer, can you get the path sorted in the `fullPath`? maybe there is an issue there.

Comment: as per latest swift , use  `try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: path) `

Answer (score 73):

In case anyone needs this for the latest Swift / Xcode versions: here is an example to remove all files from the temp folder:

**Swift 2.x:**

```
func clearTempFolder() {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let tempFolderPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    do {
        let filePaths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(tempFolderPath)
        for filePath in filePaths {
            try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(tempFolderPath + filePath)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not clear temp folder: \(error)")
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.x** and **Swift 4:**

```
func clearTempFolder() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let tempFolderPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    do {
        let filePaths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: tempFolderPath)
        for filePath in filePaths {
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: tempFolderPath + filePath)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Could not clear temp folder: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you concat "tempFolderPath" with "filePath" since "filePath is already the full path of the item listed in the folder ? Just do "try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: filePath)" is enough I think.

Comment: @Lapinou He is deleting contents of a folder.

Comment: @BlindNinja Yep indeed :)

Comment: @joern This answer saved me a ton of headaches!!!!!!! THANK YOU FOR THIS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 19):

**Swift 4.0** example that removes all files from an example folder "`diskcache`" in the documents directory. I found the above examples unclear because they used the `NSTemporaryDirectory() + filePath` which is not "url" style. For your convenience:

```
    func clearDiskCache() {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let myDocuments = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let diskCacheStorageBaseUrl = myDocuments.appendingPathComponent("diskCache")
        guard let filePaths = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: diskCacheStorageBaseUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: []) else { return }
        for filePath in filePaths {
            try? fileManager.removeItem(at: filePath)
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice this is helpful for swift 4, can confirm it works!

Answer (score 16):

**Swift 3**:

```
 func clearTempFolder() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let tempFolderPath = NSTemporaryDirectory()

    do {
        let filePaths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: tempFolderPath)
        for filePath in filePaths {
            try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + filePath)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not clear temp folder: \(error.debugDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Remove all files From Document Directory: Swift 4

```
func clearAllFile() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let myDocuments = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    do {
        try fileManager.removeItem(at: myDocuments)
    } catch {
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from the 6 other answers that have been posted over the past 3 years? Add some explanation to show how this is a useful answer.

Comment: This example is useful because it removes files from the documentDirectory and not the cache or tempDirectory.

Comment: Won't this remove the entire directory, not just its contents?

Answer (score 2):

**Create Temp Folder in Document Directory (Swift 4)**

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        //        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        //        return paths[0]

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if let tDocumentDirectory = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let filePath =  tDocumentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MY_TEMP")
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) {
                do {
                    try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: filePath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                } catch {
                    NSLog("Couldn't create folder in document directory")
                    NSLog("==> Document directory is: \(filePath)")
                    return fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
                }
            }

            NSLog("==> Document directory is: \(filePath)")
            return filePath
        }
        return fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    }
```

**Remove Files From Temp Directory: (Swift 4)**

```
func clearAllFilesFromTempDirectory(){        
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            let strTempPath = getDocumentsDirectory().path
            let filePaths = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: strTempPath)
            for filePath in filePaths {
                try fileManager.removeItem(atPath: strTempPath + "/" + filePath)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Could not clear temp folder: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**After research, I find this perfect solution,**

You can **delete all files & folders,** this will skip hidden files (for example, .DS_Store)

```
func clearCache(){
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        let documentDirectoryURL = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        for url in fileURLs {
           try fileManager.removeItem(at: url)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple func to delete a file from app Documents folder.

```
func removeItem(_ relativeFilePath: String) {
    guard let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return }
    let absoluteFilePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(relativeFilePath)
    try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: absoluteFilePath)
}
```

Usage:

```
removeItem("path/to/file.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Files**

https://github.com/JohnSundell/Files

```
    do {
        for folder:Folder in (FileSystem().documentFolder?.subfolders)! {
            try folder.delete()
        }
    } catch _ {
        print("Error")
    }
```