# How to add an image as background at run time in swift and keep it?

Tags: ios, swift3

Good morning I am writing an app in Swift 3.1, and one of the features that I would like to provide is that the user can choose their own background for the main View and keep it as part of the application.

I know how to do it at design time, but what I want is to allow the user once they install the application on their devices to select a picture from the photo library and use that as background of the main View. Also I would like to make sure the app doesn't the depend on the photo library after the image was set as background, in other words, I want to copy the image to the app so if the user deletes the image from the photo library, I have a copy of the image as part of the app.

May I ask if what I want to achieve is possible? If so may I ask for some code guidance please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be acheive by following steps:

1) You need to implement UIImagePickerController to select a photo from photos library.

https://turbofuture.com/cell-phones/Access-Photo-Camera-and-Library-in-Swift

2) You need to write a code to save that image in your Application document folder

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/04/save-and-get-image-from-document.html

3) You need to write code to delete the existing image otherwise app size will increase.

[Delete files from directory inside Document directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32840190/delete-files-from-directory-inside-document-directory)

4) Get image from Application document folder and add it to your view as background.

https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/04/save-and-get-image-from-document.html