# Files are 0 bytes

Tags: ios, swift, filesystems

#### Question

Why is it showing that `Developer` is the only directory that contains anything? There are directories like `System`, `Library`, and `Applications` which I know are not `0`.

#### Code

```
print(ViewController.getSizeOfFolders(startingAt: "/"))
```

---

```
    private static func getSizeOfFolders(startingAt:String) -> [Int] {
        let dirs = getFiles(inFolder: startingAt)
        var out:[Int] = []
        for dir in dirs {
            out.append(getSize(ofFolder: dir))
        }
        return out
    }

    private static func getSize(ofFolder:URL) -> Int {
        var folderSize = 0
        (try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: ofFolder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil))?.lazy.forEach {
            folderSize += (try? $0.resourceValues(forKeys: [.totalFileAllocatedSizeKey]))?.totalFileAllocatedSize ?? 0
        }
        print("\(ofFolder): \(folderSize)")

        return folderSize
    }

    private static func getFiles(inFolder:String) -> [URL] {
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:inFolder)
        do {
            let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: fileURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
            return directoryContents
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return []
        }
    }
```

#### Output

```
file:///.HFS+%20Private%20Directory%20Data%0D/: 0
file:///.file: 0
file:///.mb/: 0
file:///Applications/: 0
file:///Developer/: 16384
file:///Library/: 0
file:///System/: 0
file:///bin/: 0
file:///cores/: 0
file:///dev/: 0
file:///etc: 0
file:///private/: 0
file:///sbin/: 0
file:///tmp: 0
file:///usr/: 0
file:///var: 0
[0, 0, 0, 0, 16384, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Your application is Sandboxed

Comment: @LeoDabus is there any way to get around that?

Comment: Of course not. You can't access the urls and/or any information outside your Bundle

Comment: Is it a macOS or an iOS question? your question but is tagged as iOS https://stackoverflow.com/a/32814710/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus It is an iOS question. I was trying to get how much storage everything took up like how in Settings/General/iPhone Storage it shows you what is taking up what space.

Comment: The only thing you can get that it is not regarding your Bundle is how much free space there is available.

Comment: That's a shame, thanks for your help.